# java - Automatically add a JMenuItem inside a JMenu

Tags: java, jmenu, jmenuitem

This is my main problem, how to make a working program that a **for loop** will automatically add a JMenuItem inside of a JMenu.

It's supposedly like this:
When I insert a link to the program, it'll automatically put the link and the file name/folder to the JMenuItem inside the JMenu.

This is my code that I'm working on:

```
    int paths = 0;

    for(int a = 0; a < paths; a++) {

        int count = a + 1;

        itemPath = new JMenuItem(count + chooser.getAbsolutePath);

        menuPaths.add(itemPath);

    }
```

Comment: How will  you add a link to your program? I would recommend to just call the `menuPaths.add` method, after you've added your link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided I understand your question correctly...

Do you want to add an infinite number of `JMenuItem`'s into a `JMenu`?

If this is the case then you should probably be asking yourself if this is absolutely necessary as your code will crash quickly.

However, you can use a while loop as follows

```
    int paths = 0;
    while(true) {
        count++;
        itemPath = new JMenuItem(count + chooser.getAbsolutePath);
        menuPaths.add(itemPath);

    }
```

If, however, you're wondering why your current code isn't working, I would recommend you look at your `for` loop where you're checking if `a < paths` where `paths` and `a` have both been initialized to 0 and therefore your loop isn't even executing.

Comment: That is the question that I need and edited for you can understand and thanks it woked properly. That's why **for loops** dosent work.